# I need to augment my output to include cat-ing a file in this Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I have a script querying a remote server based on user input and looks for the last modified date of a file. It works, however, contained in the file is a string that I need to have displayed as well and everything I've tried has been for naught. I would really appreciate any help.

**Script**

```
echo "Input server name:"
read server
echo "Input user:"
read user

ssh $server "find /home/  -maxdepth 2 -name .lastlogin | xargs -l -I{} bash -c '{
stat -c \"User: %U Last Login : %y\" {} | cut -c -47 |grep $user; 
}'"
```

**Current Sample Output**

```
User: owner Last Login : 2014-07-24 15:05:39
```

I need this output to include the contents of this file, `.lastlogin`, which happens to be an IP address.

**Desired Sample Output**

```
User: owner Last Login : 2014-07-24 15:05:39 From: 172.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this, worked great.

```
echo "Server name:"
read server
echo "Search for user:"
read user

OUTPUT1=$(ssh $server "find /home/$user/.lastlogin | xargs -l -I{} bash -c '{
stat -c \"User: %U Last Login : %y\" {} | cut -c -47;
}'")

OUTPUT2=$(ssh $server "cat /home/$user/.lastlogin")

echo "$OUTPUT1 From: $OUTPUT2"
exit
```

Output:

```
User: owner Last Login : 2014-07-24 15:05:39 From: 172.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
ssh $server "readlink -f /home/$user/.lastlogin | \
    xargs -l -I{} bash -c '{
      stat -c \"User: %U Last Login : %y\" {} | cut -c -47 | grep $user;
      echo -n \"From: \" ; cat {} ; echo ; 
    }'"
```

I would use `readlink -f` instead of `find`.